# How to get public key of a secure webpage?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

How can I get the public key of a webpage like verisign , etc. using HTTPS protocol?

Comment: If I understand your question right then, you can click on the https protocol sign in chrome or firefox (on the  left corner of the address bar), there you can see a pop showing detail about the certificate including its public key.

Comment: @Jor-el, I'm assuming from the [tag:openssl] tag that the question is about doing this with OpenSSL. Perhaps the question could be clarified.

Comment: An HTTPS _page_ does not have a publickey; only a _server_ has a publickey, and certificate for it, as explained in the answers. That is at least one domainname, and sometimes more than one. Different pages _can't_ have different keys/certs, because the server must provide its cert (and the client accept it) before the client informs the server what page is requested -- if any; HTTP[S] allows requests that don't access any page at all.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This command will show you the certificate (use `-showcerts` as an extra parameter if you want to see the full chain):

```
openssl s_client -connect the.host.name:443
```

This will get the certificate and print out the public key:

```
openssl s_client -connect the.host.name:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

If you want to dig further, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117100/372643) might be of interest.

Comment: When running this on CentOS 7 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k, the command doesn't exit automatically after printing the key.

Comment: works on Qubes release 4.1.1, I can confirm;

Answer (score 10):

In google chrome, go to the https web page (say https://mail.google.com), click on the lock next to the URL, then click on "certificate information", click on the "Details" tab, and then find "Subject Public Key Info", which for `mail.google.com` says Subject Public Key Algorithm: "PKCS #1 RSA Encryption" and Subject's Public Key:

```
Modulus (1024 bits):
AF 39 15 98 68 E4 92 FE 4F 4F F1 BB FF 0D 2E B0
FE 25 AA BD 68 04 67 27 EA 6C 43 4C A7 6D CB C8
8F 7E 81 EE 87 26 25 10 12 54 33 9E AA 3D 9B 8F
8E 92 B3 4B 01 E3 F9 4A 29 C3 0F FD AC B7 D3 4C
97 29 3F 69 55 CF 70 83 04 AF 2E 04 6E 74 D6 0F
17 09 FE 9E 20 24 24 E3 C7 68 9C AC 11 BD 92 E4
B2 1B 09 F2 02 32 BB 55 1B 2D 16 5F 30 12 23 E2
4C 4A 8D C2 DA 3F E1 B8 BF F7 3A B1 86 BE F0 C5

Public Exponent (24 bits):
01 00 01
```

This corresponds to the decimal numbers `N=123045765072979014913511278179231402316770142733119510397469126703890433473616878571037576880489731114142173557070569117331013682110047985574967516701153320350820086344743718518661070276817382223900929884490765709232088941906671668904441902033030813416432622693650320785674286428555963210887699747381872357573`

and `exponent=65537` used in RSA.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, [SSLSocket.getpeercert](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) can be used to obtain the peer certificate, which in turn can be parsed by any DER certificate parser:

```
import ssl, socket
from asn1crypto import pem, x509

hostname = 'www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl'
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname)
s.connect((hostname, 443))
der = s.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
cert = x509.Certificate.load(der)
pubkey = cert.public_key.unwrap()
print(pubkey)
```

The variable `pubkey` is now a `RSAPublicKey` if the connection used RSA. You can get the modulus like this:

```
print(pubkey["modulus"].native)
```

Or convert it to a PEM public key like this:

```
print(pem.armor("PUBLIC KEY", pubkey.contents).decode("ASCII"))
```